# A Riddle of Feelings

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Here is my riddle:

```
I help people show their feelings,
but I am fairly new.
A few of me are purple
and some are partially blue.

I am used more by the young
than I am the old.
And a lot of me have recently
changed from yellow to gold.

I can show you that
your friend is about to cry, and
now, just answer this simple question:
What am I?
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you

> Emoji

I help people show their feelings,
but I am fairly new.

> It does help people show their feelings while chatting. And these have been in trend for past decades.

A few of me are purple
and some are partially blue.

> Some Emojis come in purple color. And some are partially blue like ;) or :'(

I am used more by the young
than I am the old.

> The new generation use them more than old.

And a lot of me have recently
changed from yellow to gold.

> Some Emojis have been changed from yellow to gold.

I can show you that
your friend is about to cry, and
now, just answer this simple question:
What am I?

> Emoji :'( show that.

Answer (score 6):

are you

> A mood ring

I help people show their feelings,

> supposedly mood rings show feelings(moods)

but I am fairly new.

> Mood rings were only invented in the seventies

A few of me are purple
and some are partially blue.

> They tend to change color

I am used more by the young
than I am the old.

> Mood rings are usually popular with kids moreso than grownups

And a lot of me have recently
changed from yellow to gold.

> again, color changing is part of what make moodrings fun

I can show you that
your friend is about to cry, and

> Crying, again talking about moods

now, just answer this simple question:
What am I?

> A mood ring!

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the answer I had in mind.